# Should I use prepared statements for MySQL in PHP PERFORMANCE-WISE?

Tags: php, mysql, performance, pdo, prepared-statement

I understand the security benefits of prepared statements in MySQL. No need to cover that topic here. I'm wondering about the performance aspect of them.

Now, I know when a query using a prepared statement is executed twice in a single PHP script, it's faster because the query is only parsed once, once for each query. The client makes one trip to prepare, then sends data twice using the binary protocol. The binary protocol is faster, and you're not taking the hit of having to parse a second time.

However, what about the case where I only want to perform a query once in a single PHP script?  It would seem using a prepared statement is worse, because you're making two trips to the server, once to prepare, and once to send the data. The benefit of only having to parse once is lost, and you're penalized for that second trip. If the data isn't sufficiently smaller in binary format, you lose by using a prepared statement, right?

However, I've read some conflicting reports about what PHP's mysqli or PDO libraries do? Do either of them cache the prepared statement across script execution? Is the server going to have to parse the prepared statement again on a subsequent pageload or not? If the answer is no, that the statement doesn't have to be parsed on the second pageload, then it would seem that prepared statements ARE better, even if you're only executing the query once per pageload.

Please take into consideration if anything has changed between versions of MySQL regarding this. You can safely assume I'm using PHP 5.2

EDIT: Just to make it clear, I want an answer for MySQL and PHP specifically, specifying the MySQL version and if this was ever different, and to ONLY consider performance, not ease of use or security.

UPDATE: I accepted the answer I did because of the follow up comment had a few good ideas. I'm still a bit disappointed that no one seems to be able to answer the crux of the actual question I asked with any certainty. I guess sometimes the answer really is "it depends."

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### The History

This was my first Stackoverflow answer. A lot has changed since, specially the deprecation and removal of the mysql API. Even if you are still on php 5.6, the mysql_* api should not be used. Now PDO or mysqli are the only options to choose. PDO is better to lots of reasons.

### Are prepared statements cached across page loads?

> I've read some conflicting reports about what PHP's mysqli or PDO
>   libraries do? Do either of them cache the prepared statement across
>   script execution?

The same prepared statement will not be used in between page loads. It has to be prepared every time. If squeezing every large millisecond matters, a stored procedure might be a good idea (assuming you have a complicated query).

For large inserts (thousands of rows) A bigger boost can probably be gained by dumping your data into a text file and loading it with LOAD DATA IN FILE . It's a lot faster than a series of inserts.

### The original answer

The truth of the matter is that sometimes mysqli is faster and at other times mysql api is faster. But the difference is really really small. If you look at any of the performance tests on the web the difference is really just 10 - 20 milliseconds. The best way to boost performance is to optimize table design.

Many of the tests that 'prove' the older api to be faster conveniently forget that for maximum security mysql_real_escape_string() should be called for each variable used in the query.

Queries are cached by the server, if and only if the data on all the tables that are used in the query have remained unchanged.

**Await another update with actual numbers**

Comment: Yeah. I've already got a strong hand on table optimization. I'm not really asking about the query cache either. I'm asking about caching of a prepared statement to avoid having to reparse it in between page loads. Also, a lot of my queries are just inserting integers, so I do have the situation where I can just run intval on the input instead of mysql_real_escape_string. Also, 10 milliseconds do matter to me as I feel I've optimized whatever else I can.

Comment: The same prepared statment will not be used in between page loads. It has to be prepared every time.

If  squeezing every large millisecond matters, a store procedure might be a good idea (assuming you have a complicated query)

A bigger boost can probably be gained by dumping your data into a text file and loading it with LOAD DATA IN FILE . It's a lot faster than a series of inserts.

Answer (score 8):

"Using prepared statements is never really a bad idea"

Not true. You can easily fill up the prepared statement cache and exceed `max_prepared_stmt_count` if you don't know what you're doing, rendering your app useless until connections consuming the prepared statements are closed.

Prepared statements are specifically designed for tight inner loops in your business logic where you're going to be calling the same basic query over and over again, a good example being a parameterized query such as:

```
SELECT name, address, phone from tbl WHERE id = ?
```

and you have a different id on each call.  That way, it's worth the extra round trip to the db for the prepare because you're probably going to call it hundreds or thousands of times and just change the parameter.  But you're expected to remove the prepared statement from the cache or close the connection at the end of, say, your stateless script (php, perl, jsp, ruby, etc).
If you don't remove the prepared statement and you are using a connection pool, you are bound to fill up the cache over time and get a nasty error "Can't create more than max_prepared_stmt_count statements".  I'm speaking from experience so think about whether you really need prepared statements because you know definitively that you're going  to be repeating the same parameterized query over and over in a tight loop.
If not, what you're probably looking for is letting mysql use its basic query cache which is a different mechanism than the prepared statement list and which behaves like a true LRU cache from my understanding.

Answer (score 1):

Not for all cases. There are times when prepared statements perform **slower** than a manually constructed query **even though it's run repeatedly**.

For example, when I need to insert hundreds of rows in one page load, I find:

```
$pdo -> query("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (".$pdo -> quote($value1).", ".$pdo -> quote($value2).", ...), (row2), (row3), ..., (row100), ...");
```

A LOT faster than:

```
$stmt = $pdo -> prepare("INSERT INTO table (field1, field2, ...) VALUES (:value1, :value2, ...)");
foreach (/* some hundred times */) {
  $stmt -> execute(array('value1' => $value1, 'value2' => $value2, ...));
}
```

## UPDATE

I wrote this answer 4 years ago since then I've learned new things about this.

For the prepared statement that is repeatedly run hundreds of times to be fast, you have to wrap all the executions in **one transaction**.

However I never tested which is faster, non-prepared single batch INSERT with 1000 rows or 1000 executions of prepared INSERT wrapped in a transaction.

Comment: Folks, I need any seconders for this answer!

Answer (score 0):

Using prepared statements is never really a bad idea. I've not used them recently with mySQL, but I've used them heavily with SQLSERVER - and they work great.

The PDO library probably doesn't do any caching but the database will for the prepared statement.

Plus as you covered they are great for security. Its also really nice to push that logic out of the code - you wont up with SQL sprinkled throughout your application.

Comment: So MySQL will not have to parse the query on the second pageload? Are you sure? Do you have any documentation? And what version of MySQL are we talking about here? Or is this only for SQLSERVER?

Answer (score 0):

What exactly do you mean "parsed on the second pageload"?

Each PHP process/thread/visitor that executes that same script again will NOT prevent MySQL from re-parsing the query to prepare the statement, as its valid in a per connection basis, so its very effective for queries repeated in the same script.

Now, I cant argue about prepare + execute vs simple query, performance wise (w/o repeated queries);

But, to save mysql from parsing a complex query in every single script execution, you should use stored procedures; a query would be just `CALL items(date,search_etc,id);` instead of `SELECT i.id FROM products as p JOIN item_prodct as t ON... JOIN items as i... ON... WHERE ... p.date ... i.search_etc ...`

You can use stored procedures with prepared statements.

Comment: What about when you are using persistent connections or pdo connection polling?

Comment: and what I meant by parsed on the second pageload is that some have implied that using persistent connections or pooling will allow the connection to be kept open and therefore a statement previously prepared will be again available. I know, it sounding like nonsense to me too, but that's why I asked the question. You can see that the other answerer to this question seems to think otherwise.

Comment: well, using ur application functions for prep_stmt Maybe, in PHP MySQLi for instance, how would you carry the stmt_init() object around ? Im not shure.. Dont know much about PDO sorry  

__but__ there is SQL syntax for prepared statetements, you can use even through command line, you basically assign a name to the stmt, and reference it later by that name, the parameters are session variables so __YES__ using persistent connections you could achieve that, it would be almost like a stored procedure, but with ability to return multiple rows

Comment: you would hardcode a variable name and stmt name, and if the variable iscreated<>yes you then prepare the stmt.. this is for whenever the persistent connection is droped....    
.........
and another BUT is that each script or thread should use unique variable names, so that thread dont mess with each other data,

Comment: Thanks for the attempts, are you now saying there is a way to not have to reparse the prepared statement on the second page load?

Comment: Yes, since statements belong the the session/connection  Check it out http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/sql-syntax-prepared-statements.html  ---- you save the mysql optimizer a lot of work, but i think u lose all the other advantages of prepstmt, but still seems a nice way to go