# PHP - Difference between all PDO transaction and stricly MySQL transaction?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo, transactions

I've been searching the web for about 2 days trying to identify the differences and possible advantages/disadvantages to using all PDO or all MySQL for transactions.

I'm doing approximately 20 inserts per member and you can register multiple members simultaneously so the number of queries can go from 20 to 100+ easily and our estimation of activity can range from hundreds to thousands of these to occur per hour.

I know about transactions but what I don't seem to grasp is if there's much difference between having all of the inserts batched into one PDO prepare or to have them all separated.
Example:

```
$stmt1 = $pdo->prepare($query1);
$stmt2 = $pdo->prepare($query2);
$stmt3 = $pdo->prepare($query3);
$stmt4 = $pdo->prepare($query4);
....

$pdo->beginTransaction();

try{
  foreach($members as $member)
  {
    $stmt1->execute($member);
    $stmt2->execute($member);
    $stmt3->execute($member);
    $stmt4->execute($member);
    ....
  }
  $pdo->commit();
catch(Exception $e)
{
  $pdo->rollback();
}
```

Compared to something along the lines:

```
//Inserts for ALL members
$sql = "
START TRANSACTION;
INSERT INTO...;
INSERT INTO...;
INSERT INTO...;
INSERT INTO...;
INSERT INTO...;
INSERT INTO...;
COMMIT;";

try{
  $pdo->prepare($sql);
  $stmt->execute($member);

catch(Exception $e)
{
  $pdo->query("ROLLBACK;");
}
```

Can this create overhead with having to send the queries one at a time and then continue parsing on the PHP side or could it benefit to send it all at once through one PDO call?

**UPDATE**

I noticed the confusion in the second example, I've editted it. For clarity, the question is referring to potential "hang-up" in high-volume traffic using multiple PHP-side queries (PDO executing each SQL statement one at a time, still within ONE transaction) compared to sending a large block of SQL with one PDO execute (still only ONE transaction).

Comment: In your first snippet, either the `$pdo->beginTransaction()` or the `$pdo->commit();` is misplaced. They should be both inside or both outside the loop. I suppose your question is when they are outside the loop? If both inside, then your two approches are strictly equivalent.

Comment: You're right, I rushed through the example. Regardless, this isn't the direct code. I'm more interested in the differences between the two possible methods.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I read the [PDO documentation on transactions](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.transactions.php), both methods are equivalent.  That is, PDO will use the driver-level transaction capabilities which, in the case of pdo_mysql, *should* be starting a native MySQL transaction.

I think the bigger issue to consider is exactly what you want to achieve.  Are you using a transaction for performance reasons, or because the data is related and nothing should be inserted if one statement fails?

If the former, I would recommend benchmarking it.  If the latter you need to structure the code such that logically related data are within the same transaction.

---

***Edit in response to question update:***

I'm inclined to say that issuing one large SQL statement would be quicker since there should be a bit less network traffic overhead (assuming the web and database servers aren't on the same host).  With 'good' hardware and the correct configuration for your application requirements MySQL should be able to handle many thousands of inserts a second.

Of course, without knowing the details of your setup, this is pure speculation.  But I suspect this kind of application-level optimisation is much less effective than tuning the database server.

The only way to be sure is to benchmark both ways and see if one is significantly better than the other.

Comment: I'm using transactions in a sense of integrity whereas if one fails nothing should be added. Thank you for the insight.

Comment: I realized some slight confusion in the second example, the insert statements would include ALL members with one commit at the end.

Comment: Thank you for your response on the update, it's much appreciated. I found a question that is similar (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10863598/mysql-php-pdo-prepared-statements-performance-issues-vs-security) and the response was the same as yours; "premature optimization".

Answer (score 3):

Whether you use the PDO API or the native (My)SQL statement is somewhat irrelevant. The difference in performance will be close to zero, as PDO is just abstraction class that issues SQL statements at the end of the day*. In other words:

```
$pdo->beginTransaction();
$stmt1->execute($query1);
$stmt2->execute($query2);
$pdo->commit();
```

... is really the same as:

```
$stmt1->execute('START TRANSACTION;' . $query1 . $query2 . 'COMMIT;');
```

Your actual concern is whether it is better to create each member in a separate transaction, or all members in one single global transaction. Most often, it is faster to insert everything in one transaction.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying. This was more of an insecurity a colleague of mine has. If using the beginTransaction() is essentially the same as the other, then that answers my question spot on. The concern was more of a question if the PDO object, sends a request, comes back, sends another request and so on; slows down since you're communicating from application to database on every query.

Comment: I realized some slight confusion in the second example, the insert statements would include ALL members with one commit at the end.