# Is it really nesseccary to PREPARE statements with PHP's mysqli?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

At the moment I have some database wrapper functions like so:

```
function db_escape($str) {
    return mysql_real_escape_string($str);
}

function db_query($sql) {
    global $LINKID;
    return mysql_query ($sql, $LINKID);
}

function db_fetch_array($result) {
    return mysql_fetch_array ($result, MYSQL_ASSOC);
}
```

In my code I can then do things like:

```
$result = db_query('SELECT userid, first_name, last_name FROM user 
                    WHERE email = "' . db_escape($email) . '"');

if ($result) {
    $user = db_fetch_array($result);
}
```

One of the ideas behind this is that when I switch from mysql to mysqli, it'll take just a few minutes to update my wrapper functions and I don't have to replace hundreds of instances of `mysql_real_escape_string()`, `mysql_query()` and `mysql_fetch_array()` across hundreds of different projects.

The only issue with this is that the above can translate to standard procedural mysqli functions easily enough, but not prepared statements.

Does this matter?  It seems like every tutorial says prepared statements are important for security and performance, however at the moment:

1. None of my projects have performance issues.
2. I am extremely anal about casting user input to the expected type (string, integer, float, etc.) and also manually escaping any user input that's used anywhere in a query.

With this in mind is it really necessary to switch to prepared statements, for either past or future projects?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Should I use prepared statements for MySQL in PHP PERFORMANCE-WISE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214408/should-i-use-prepared-statements-for-mysql-in-php-performance-wise)

Comment: The above is not an exact dupe, but still pretty much covers your question.

Comment: You could add an optional second argument to your `db_query` function; if it is not empty, it contains an array with the variables and the statement has to be prepared. Then you can use both. However, it would not make your sql *safer*, you're good with `mysqli_real_escape_string` (note the character set warning in the manual).

Comment: Thanks hjpotter92, I read the other question which talks about performance.  Again, there's a few people there implying that prepared statements are secure and non-prepared statements aren't, which I think is incorrect if you properly sanitize and escape your user input.

Comment: @MrCarrot :) everything is secured as long as you do it RIGHT (100% RIGHT), but sometime you don't or your mate doesn't or you think you do it RIGHT but you don't. That's why people create something that helps you to do it right or enforce you to do it right. You can also go wrong with prepared_statement, but the chance is lesser and the damage is smaller than a normal mysql_query.

Comment: Thanks for the comments and answers.  I think both answers below are essentially correct.  I find it annoying that people talk as if non-prepared statements are not secure when this is not necessarily the case.  However I take on board all comments, especially the fact that it might not always be me working on a project, and that it only requires a single mistake to lead to a catastrophe.  

Also thanks to Jeroen for the suggestion above regarding how I can modify my db_query function to make use of prepared statements, I think I am going to do this in the near future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should think about the long term benefit. For example, if in the future you are no longer the developer of that project, the habit of using non-prepared statement will be passed down to the next developer and this:

> I am extremely anal about casting user input to the expected type (string, integer, float, etc.) and also manually escaping any user input that's used anywhere in a query.

may not be true anymore. And even though you say you're very careful, at some point you will make mistake or forget (yes people did! and that's why things break) then it will be an issue.

Think about the following case as an example. Do you think it's safe ?

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$result = db_query('SELECT userid, first_name, last_name FROM user 
                WHERE userid = ' . db_escape($id) );
```

Comment: I would start this off as:

$id = isset ($_POST['id']) ? (int) $_POST['id'] : 0;

But I take on board your comments about mistakes and/or other people who aren't anal about escaping input.

Answer (score 0):

Although I feel somewhat irritated seeing yet another Mr. Smart who come up with his *Perpetuum Mobile*, I cannot call his ideas totally unreasonable to some degree. But, unfortunately, they are all based on the **wrong assumptions.**

Which are

- SQL formatting rules are limited to escaping and casting
- whatever protection from SQL injection required
- such a protection should be applied to user input
- every PHP application is small and observable
- like it was mentioned in the other answer, only one developer, who keeps all the code in his head, ever works on the project.

But again, all these assumptions are wrong.

As soon as you rethink them, you will come to conclusion that only the **parameterized query** can give you an insurance bill. Note that I am talking of the general idea of using parameters, not particular implementation used in mysqli. One can have the idea implemented even with old mysql ext all right.

Another thing to think of is code beauty and size. Look what you have now

```
$result = db_query('SELECT userid, first_name, last_name FROM user 
                    WHERE email = "' . db_escape($email) . '"');
if ($result) {
    $user = db_fetch_array($result);
}
```

and what it can be using parameters

```
$sql = 'SELECT userid, first_name, last_name FROM user WHERE email = ?';
$user = db_fetch_array($sql, $email);
```