# changing from mysql to mysqli standard proceedure - prepared statements?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am editing a tutorial I found on inline editing. It uses mysql but obviously I want to use mysqli as mysql is depreciated. I have changed most of it but one part is causing me difficulty. There is a seperate file that is called to connect to the database and run queries so the main page I will declare at the top at the top of my page I declare

```
require_once("dbcontroller.php");
$db_handle = new DBController();
$sql = "SELECT * from php_interview_questions";
$faq = $db_handle->runQuery($sql);
```

The relevant part of the dbcontroller.php is:

```
function runQuery($query) {
        $result = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
        while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $resultset[] = $row;
        }       
        if(!empty($resultset))
            return $resultset;
    }

    function numRows($query) {
        $result  = mysqli_query($conn,$query);
        $rowcount = mysqli_num_rows($result);
        return $rowcount;   
    }
```

Am I right in thinking that I need to use prepared statements? If so how would this cope with working with a select query that could involve any number of columns or any number of conditions in the WHERE clause?

Comment: The statement you show there doesn't need prepared statements, since there is no user input in a `WHERE` clause. Relating to your closing paragraph: if you have need to add a variable number of filtering clauses, just use string manipulation to build them, and then add the right number of parameters in your bind calls.

Comment: I'm just wondering why would you think you need prepared statements?

Comment: @Patrick I kinda do understand he wants to use prepared statements... He actually runs 1 method which will handle everything related to querying. Which means if he will use a where clause it shall go with prepared statements....

Comment: @MikeM. Of course the general reasons on why to use prepared statements are obvious, I was just wondering if the OP understands why, as normally , as halfer said, data binding will be enough. There doesn't seem to be a specific reason to use prepared statements over any other security method

Comment: See related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2214408/should-i-use-prepared-statements-for-mysql-in-php-performance-wise

Comment: Oh @Patrick I actually misunderstood your comment then. I thought you meant it as "why would you use it the when it's not needed" as in its case not to question the op if he knows it or not; my apologies.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

numRows() is a strange function since it runs a query only to find out how many rows it returns. I would consider it a questionable practice. If it is necessary to find out how many rows a SELECT would return, then one could change SELECT * to SELECT COUNT(*). MySQL would be able to optimize that for MyISAM tables, plus there is a saving on not having to transfer the result set to the client.

Otherwise there is no need to use prepared statements, since a prepared statement only increases the amount of work a DBMS has to do when a statement is executed only once (it has to handle two requests -  prepare, execute, -- instead of one -- execute, plus extra work to clean up the cached statement when connection is destroyed).